# How do I bind object model within an ng-repeat directive to a single kendo-window popup

Tags: angularjs, model, kendo-ui, bind

**Html**:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>DOB</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="member in model.Members" ng-dblclick="Member(member)">
       <td>{{member.Name}}</td>
       <td>{{member.DOB | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<div kendo-window="*dialog*" k-title="'Member Profile'" k-visible="false" k-modal="true" k-width="700" k-height="410" k-resizable="false">
    <ng-familymember controller="familycontroller"></ng-familymember>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
function fooController($scope) {
  $scope.Member = function (familyMember) {
     $scope.*dialog*.center().open();
  }
}
```

**Problem**:
I have a collection of objects (i.e. model.Members) used within an ng-repeat directive and I want to be able to double-click on a row and bind the object model to a kendo-window (popup). Inside my controller I'm passing in the model to a function (i.e. Member()) within the controller but I'm not sure how to pass/bind this model to the kendo-window? I could simply move the kendo-window html inside the ng-repeat and use the ng-model directive but that would repeat the kendo-window html (n) times and I don't want that.

**Any Suggestions**?
I've tried binding the member object to an $scope variable. (i.e. $scope.familyMember = familyMember;). Because the way Prototypal Inheritance works I'm actually creating a copy of the familyMember object and using that in the kendow-window popup.

You should know that I'm also setting up a $watch within the controller on the member object to notify other directives on the page of changes made within the kendo-window.

Any help would be appreciated... I'm a bit lost at this point...

Comment: How is `$scope.member` function triggered? As I understand, you double click on a row - is an `ng-click` directive associated with the row that calls the member function to open the dialog?

Comment: Yeah it's triggered via the ng-dblclick="Member(member)" directive. This part is working fine it's just that I'm not understanding how to pass the member object as a model into the kendo-window model popup.